# Tune for Nusach Nadvorna and/or Kretchnif

Tags: tefilla

Does anybody know where I could find a good, clear, example of nusach Kretchnif or Nadvorna? I've looked through Kol Torah Online but all the examples they have are older tapes with pretty rough audio quality.

By "nusach" I mean the tniois/tune of the davenen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the uninitiated (including myself), could you please clarify what nusach Kretchnif or Nadvorna are? Thanks for your question, and welcome!

Comment: Try here: they have many recordings https://web.nli.org.il/

Comment: @robev: He doesn't mean the words, but the traditional tunes. Each locality would have its own variations or particular melodies for different parts of davening. So there really would be a nusach for every community in Europe or the Sefardi areas.